# cakephp mysql group by query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In the following cakephp mysql query, how do I find number of rows grouped each time?

```
$groupBy = 'PropertyViewer.ip_address';
$this->paginate = array(
  "group" => array( $groupBy ),
  "order" => array( "PropertyViewer.id desc" ) );
$view_info = $this->paginate( 'PropertyViewer', $conditions );
$this->set( 'view_info', $view_info );`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like in the following way, however I did not try it but it will work.

```
$groupBy = 'PropertyViewer.ip_address'; 
$this->paginate = array( "fields" => (..., 'COUNT(PropertyViewer.id) AS total_rows),
                         "group" => array( $groupBy ),
                         "order" => array( "PropertyViewer.id desc" ) );
$view_info = $this->paginate( 'PropertyViewer', $conditions );
$this->set( 'view_info', $view_info );`
```

Or you can also create a virtual Field in your model, if you need it to use frequently.